# complex eigen values of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

$a$ in that case $T$ is not invertible hence $T$ is not injective and surjective. hence $(a)$ is true statement. am I right?

$b$ need not be.

$c$ is true as a three dimensional eigen space is invariant hence if I restrict characteristic polynomial on that space it is three degree must have a real root.is my intuition right? please help.

Comment: All sound good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine but I'm afraid your answer to (b) won't be so well-accepted, in spite of being correct: in mathematics, in order to show a general statement in false, you *must* give a counterexample.

I'd say to look at something like

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&...&0\\0&2&0&...&0\\..&..&..&..&..\\0&0&...&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$